# Cauchy's Integral Formula: Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have the function

$$M(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(erf\left(9-\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert\right)+1\right)$$

where $erf(x)$ is the usual error function. Since $\mathbf{r}$ is $\in \mathbb{R^2}$, I  consider $\mathbf{r}$ to be a complex number ($\in \mathbb{C}$) and call it $z$.

Since the function

$$M(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(erf\left(9-\lvert z \rvert\right)+1\right)$$

is holomorphic, I think it should be true that

$$
M(z=0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\left(erf\left(9-\lvert z \rvert\right)+1\right)}{z}dz
$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius 9 centred at the origin, via the Cauchy integral formula.

I know that $M(\mathbf{r}=0)=\pi$, but my contour integral gives

$$
M(z=0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\left(erf\left(9-\lvert 9e^{it} \rvert\right)+1\right)}{9e^{it}}9ie^{it}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
after parametrising the unit circle with $\gamma(t)=9e^{it}$ taking $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

**So**, why does $M(\mathbf{r}=0) \neq M(z=0)$?

Comment: Just edited out a few minor errors

Comment: Your $M(z)$ is not holomorphic. $z \mapsto \operatorname{erf} (9-z)$ is holomorphic, but not if you take the modulus of $z$. If $f$ is holomorphic, then $z \mapsto f(\lvert z\rvert)$ is holomorphic if and only if $f$ is locally constant.

Comment: If I set $\mathbf{r}=\epsilon$ (which is some scalar) such that $M$ is symmetric over a disk, can I get the two integrals to match?